# Sonar violation

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarlint

```
public Integer getMaxCount(String id,String type) {
    String maxCount ="SELECT MAX(ID) AS COUNT FROM STUDENT";
    try {
        return queryForObject(
            maxCount, 
            new Object[]{id,type}, 
            (rs, i) -> {return rs.getInt(COUNT);},
            "maxCount"
        );
    } catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException ex) {
        LOG.error(ex);
        return 9999;
    }
}
```

Getting below sonar violations for above block of code how to fix.

> Lambdas should be replaced with method references
>
> Lambdas containing only one statement should not nest this statement in a block

Answer (score 4):

Those are:

- [S1612 "Lambdas should be replaced with method references"](https://sonarqube.com/coding_rules#rule_key=squid%3AS1612)
- [S1602 "Lamdbas containing only one statement should not nest this statement in a block"](https://sonarqube.com/coding_rules#rule_key=squid%3AS1602)

Both pages include example on how to fix your code.

```
x -> System.out.println(x+1)
(a, b) -> a+b    //For return statement, the return keyword should also be dropped
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need block here. You can return the value using this:

```
(rs, i) -> rs.getInt(COUNT)
```